# Why do I get "Command pm-disable needs a higher bootstrap level to run"?

Tags: 7, drush

Running `drush dis varnish` in the Drupal directory gives give me this message.

> Command pm-disable needs a higher bootstrap level to run.

Running `drush --debug dis varnish -y` gives the following output.

> Phar detected. Proceeding to drush_main().
>   Loading drushrc "/home/user/.drush/drushrc.php" into "home.drush" scope.     > Cache HIT cid: 8.1.14-commandfiles-0-erased
>   Bootstrap to phase 0.
>   Bootstrap to phase 6.
>   Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrap_drupal_root()
>   Initialized Drupal 7.59 root directory at /usr/share/www/Drupal
>   Find command files for phase 1 (max=6)
>   Cache HIT cid: 8.1.14-commandfiles-1-erased
>   Cache HIT cid: 8.1.14-annotationfiles-1-erased
>   Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrap_drupal_site()
>   Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default
>   Find command files for phase 2 (max=6)
>   Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrap_drupal_configuration()
>   Find command files for phase 3 (max=6)
>   sql-query: SELECT 1;
>   Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_erased --database=dune --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_erased
>   sql-query: SHOW TABLES;
>   Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_erased --database=dune --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_erased
>   Bootstrap to phase 1.
>   Bootstrap to phase 6.
>   Bootstrap to phase 5.
>   Command pm-disable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
>   The drush command 'dis varnish' could not be executed.

`drush status` and `drush updb` work. The output of the first command is the following one.

```
Drupal version         :  7.59
Site URI               :  http://default
Database driver        :  mysql
Database hostname      :  localhost
Database port          :
Database username      :  drupaluser
Database name          :  dune
PHP configuration      :  /etc/php.ini /home/user/.drush/drush.ini
PHP OS                 :  Linux
Drush script           :  /usr/local/bin/drush
Drush version          :  8.1.14
Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
Drush configuration    :
Drush alias files      :  /home/user/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php
Drupal root            :  /usr/share/www/Drupal
Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
Site path              :  sites/default
```

Comment: You should post the output of `drush status`. That does provide some more information and we can tell what "work" really means.

Comment: I just added output for `drush status`

Comment: Does this only happen with the varnish module? (You probably have some other module that you can enable and disable for testing.)

Answer (score 1):

This generally means that drush can't identify the site information, e.g. which settings.php to use.

A quick fix is to cd into the directory with the setting.php file for the site.

A more permanent fix is to create a site specific drush alias for the site and use it.  E.g. drush @mysite dis varnish. See this [Drupal page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1401522).

Comment: Neither of those are working for me.

Comment: `drush status` and `drush updb` work though.

Comment: Hmm, I'd check the logs for errors.  This might indicate an error in the varnish uninstall script.  Also, does varnish show up in a drush pml list?  Another way to make sure you're using the right site.